# Synchronizing data in the tables

Tags: sql

I have a code and now I need to write a queries to synchronize data in the tables. But I can't understand, how to do that.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[meal1](
    [inc] [int] IDENTITY(3,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [sort] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_meal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [inc] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[meal2](
    [inc] [int] IDENTITY(3,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [sort] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_meal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [inc] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]


insert into meal1 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (4,'BB','BB')
insert into meal1 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (6,'FB','FB')
insert into meal1 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (7,'AI','AI')

insert into meal2 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (8,'UAI','UAI')
insert into meal2 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (9,'AI ELEGANCE','AI ELEGANCE')
insert into meal2 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (10,'IM','IM')
insert into meal2 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (11,'HB','HB')
insert into meal2 (incdec, name, lname)
    values (13,'HA/I','HA/I')
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: @Donal I am new in the sql, so I have no idea how to do that. I try to learn that, but for now didn't find anything

Comment: ok, I see there are issues with your SQL. I have fixed them below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of issues with your SQL. You were inserting into a column that did not exist incdec - the column name is inc. However, you do not need to insert into this column - as it will auto increment - the column is defined as an `IDENTITY` column.

The primary key names need to be unique - so I renamed the primary key on the second table to `PK_meal2`

Here is the fixed SQL. I have tested it and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[meal1](
    [inc] [int] IDENTITY(3,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [sort] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_meal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [inc] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[meal2](
    [inc] [int] IDENTITY(3,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](48) NULL,
    [sort] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_meal2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [inc] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]


insert into meal1 (name, lname)
    values ('BB','BB')
insert into meal1 (name, lname)
    values ('FB','FB')
insert into meal1 (name, lname)
    values ('AI','AI')

insert into meal2 (name, lname)
    values ('UAI','UAI')
insert into meal2 (name, lname)
    values ('AI ELEGANCE','AI ELEGANCE')
insert into meal2 (name, lname)
    values ('IM','IM')
insert into meal2 (name, lname)
    values ('HB','HB')
insert into meal2 (name, lname)
    values ('HA/I','HA/I')
```

Comment: @dima ok, glad to be of help.